# How do I automatically add slash to end of a url in spray routing?

Tags: scala, spray

It's common practice for web servers to automatically redirect users to a URL ending in a slash when that URL represents a "directory". For example, entering http://www.apache.org/licenses into a browser redirects to http://www.apache.org/licenses/ automatically.

Due to the way spray's path-segment-based route matching works, I can't see an obvious way to create this behavior for a specific path segment. Any ideas?

Comment: You are right, this was hard to do because Slash and PathEnd matchers matched more than expected and things were done automatically. For 1.1-RC1 the `rawPathPrefix` directive was introduced which allows to match exactly. With `rawPathPrefix` you can now write `rawPathPrefix("licenses" ~ PathEnd)` to specifically match the path missing the slash at the end. Also, see this discussion we are having to discuss how to make PathMatchers work more obviously: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/spray-user/S8PM4NUMZ8I/discussion

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @jrudolph. With the information in the thread, I was able to come up with the following snippet:
    `path( "licenses" ~ PathEnd ) {
      redirect("licenses/", StatusCodes.MovedPermanently )
    } ~
    pathPrefix("licenses") {
      path("") { /* do something */
      }
    }`
   I don't see an obvious way to turn this into a custom directive, though.