# How to create custom directive to reuse routes?

Tags: scala, spray

I have a route snippet that I want to reuse in multiple scenarios:

```
val dirSegment = "licenses"
path( dirSegment ~ PathEnd ) {
  redirect( dirSegment + "/", StatusCodes.MovedPermanently ) 
} ~ 
pathPrefix(dirSegment) { 
  path("") {
    /* do something */
  }
}
```

I'd like to turn this in to a directive (or parameterizable route?) where I can specify the value of the `dirSegment` val and arbitrary further routing/code in place of `path("") { /* do something */ }` white retaining the redirect behavior, looking something like the following:

```
directoryPath("licenses") {
  path("") {
    /* do something */
  }
} ~ 
directoryPath("about") {
  path("") {
    /* do somthing else */
  }
}
```

Whereas that would have equivalent behavior to the following without all the repetition:

```
val dirSegment = "licenses"
val anotherDir = "About"

path( dirSegment ~ PathEnd ) {
  redirect(dirSegment + "/", StatusCodes.MovedPermanently ) 
} ~ 
pathPrefix(dirSegment) { 
  path("") {
    /* do something */
  }
} ~
path( anotherDir ~ PathEnd ) {
  redirect(anotherDir + "/", StatusCodes.MovedPermanently ) 
} ~ 
pathPrefix(anotherDir) { 
  path("") {
    /* do something else */
  }
}
```

Note that this question was inspired by some of the discussion in [How do I automatically add slash to end of a url in spray routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556196/how-do-i-automatically-add-slash-to-end-of-a-url-in-spray-routing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write a custom directive for this.

```
// additional imports you may need
import shapeless.HNil
import spray.http.StatusCodes
import spray.routing.Directive0
import spray.routing.PathMatcher
```

Now that that's out of the way:

```
/**
 * Spray's PathEnd matches trailing optional slashes... we can't have that
 * otherwise it will cause a redirect loop.
 */
object PathEndNoSlash extends PathMatcher[HNil] {
  def apply(path: Path) = path match {
    case Path.Empty ⇒ PathMatcher.Matched.Empty
    case _          ⇒ PathMatcher.Unmatched
  }
}

/**
 * Custom directive that uses a redirect to add a trailing slashe to segment
 * if the slash isn't present.
 */
def directoryPath(segment: String) = new Directive0 {
  def happly(f: HNil ⇒ Route) =
    // first, the redirect
    pathPrefix(segment ~ PathEndNoSlash) {
      redirect("/" + segment + "/", StatusCodes.MovedPermanently) } ~
    // delegate actual work to nested directives
    pathPrefix(segment).happly(f)
}
```

Usage:

```
directoryPath("about") {
  path("a") {
    complete {
      "this is /about/a"
    }
  } ~ path("b") {
    complete {
      "this is /about/b"
    }
  } ~ path(PathEnd) {
    complete {
      "this is /about/"
    }
  }
}
```

If a user accesses `/about`, they will be forwarded to `/about/` and see "this is /about/". The nested paths `a` and `b` work as expected (that is, without redirects of their own).

*Note: This solution is for Spray 1.2.*

Comment: We changed PathMatcher behavior a bit in RC1 and probably will do again before the final release. Starting from RC1 there's `rawPathPrefix` which exactly matches without accepting any optional trailing slashes. With that in place you should be able to write `rawPathPrefix(Slash ~ segment ~ PathEnd)` to match without the slash. Otherwise, this looks good.

Comment: @jrudolph, unless PathEnd has changed, won't that still match an optional trailing slash? I recall trying various methods (possibly `rawPathPrefix`) and having problems with redirect loops until I wrote my own `PathEndNoSlash`.

Comment: Here's the PR for the migration guide I wrote this afternoon, it hopefully explains the new behavior: https://github.com/spray/spray/pull/659/files

Comment: @Andy I did a quick test - you could also do away with the PathEndNoSlash  object by (!)not-ing a Slash. `pathPrefix(segment ~ !Slash)`