# How to catch a slash-ending URL in spray-routing?

Tags: spray

Spray is kind of really easy, but I'm having problems getting to understand the routing. It's like a dog that sometimes fetches the bone, often times not. What am I missing?

Is there a way to see what routes Spray tries, and why it gives up on certain ones? That would essentially solve this. The `logRequest` I have below simply shows the request but doesn't tell me why a path failed to match it.

```
  ...
  (get & logRequest("SAY AAA:")) {
    path("results") {    
        complete("results")
    } ~
    path("results/") {    // does not work
        complete("results/")
    } ~
    complete("fallback")
  }
```

Leads to:

```
"results/aaa" -> fallback
"results/" -> fallback
"results" -> results
```

How can I grab the `"results/"` case?

Slightly similar issues: [19556196](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556196/how-do-i-automatically-add-slash-to-end-of-a-url-in-spray-routing)

Addendum:
I got it to work with `path("results" / "")`. Why did the `"results/"` not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, seems the right way to go is:

```
    (pathPrefix("results") & pathEndOrSingleSlash) {
      complete( "results[/]" )
    }
```

This will match both `results` and `results/` which is what I want.

[Discussion on the background](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/S8PM4NUMZ8I/discussion)

`pathEndOrSingleSlash` [doc with sample](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/path-directives/pathEndOrSingleSlash/)